# Try-catch error in django

Tags: python, django, try-catch

I'm trying to import orders from external database and add they to local app. Before save order I checking if carrier id exist in db. If no I save new carrier to db. Then I try to save order.

It works fine for DESC LIMIT 10,20,50 but in 100 is problem: "[E2] ObjectDoesNotExist: Carriers matching query does not exist." Why? But before saving the order I add carrier.

```
def import_carriers(id_carrier):
    sql = """SELECT id_carrier, name, url
            FROM ps_carrier WHERE id_carrier = {} """
    rows = make_query(sql.format(id_carrier))
    for row in rows:
        try:
            import_carrier = Carriers(  shop_carrier_id=row[0],
                                        name=row[1])
            import_carrier.save()
        except IntegrityError as error:
            print "Error: " + error.message
            """ carrier_id must be unique """


def import_orders():
    sql = """SELECT id_order, id_carrier, current_state, id_lang, date_add 
            FROM ps_orders ORDER BY id_order DESC LIMIT 100"""
    rows = make_query(sql)
    for row in rows:
        try:
            delivery = Carriers.objects.get(shop_carrier_id=row[1])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as error:
            print "[E] ObjectDoesNotExist: " + error.message
            """ shop_carrier_id must exists so import carrier """
            import_carriers(row[1])
        try:
            print "import: " + str(row[0])
            delivery = Carriers.objects.get(shop_carrier_id=row[1])
            import_order = Order(   shop_order_id=row[0], 
                                    delivery=delivery, 
                                    status=row[2], 
                                    order_type=1, 
                                    lang=row[3],
                                    date=row[4])
            import_order.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as error:
            print "[E2] ObjectDoesNotExist: " + error.message
            """ shop_carrier_id must exists so import carrier """
            import_carriers(row[1])
        except IntegrityError as error:
            print "[E] IntegrityError: " + error.message
            """ shop_order_id must be unique, no duplicate """
            return
```

Comment: if you debug, what's the value of row[1] when you recieve the Exception?

Comment: omg... Older orders has carrier_id which no longer exist, so I can't import them. Thank You very much for good direction!

Why I can't see Except error from other function?